How to make link previews work again in WhatsApp?
Suddenly, my link previews don't work in WhatsApp anymore. I am sending links from major newspaper sites (like for example The Guardian) and WhatsApp doesn't show me a previews of the respective links.
I checked Settings > Privacy > Advanced > Disable link previews - and it is turned off. I tried to turn it on and then off again and it doesn't work no matter it's turned on or off.
My telephone is a Redmi Note 9S with Android 12 and it worked very well for 3 years now.
Is there anything I can do in order for WhatsApp to show me link previews again?
